# iOS 16.2 Upgrade -> "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

After upgrading my iPhone 13 Pro Max to iOS 16.2, I started getting the below error when trying to run my app via Xcode. Not 100% certain that was the cause but there's strong correlation. I'd love any guidance on additional troubleshooting; thank you!

**Things I've tried that haven't fixed the problem**:

- Upgrading Xcode and MacOS
- Disabling/enabling my device in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
- Disabling device in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and allowing Xcode to re-enabling it by attempting to Run on device
- Creating a new development profile in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
- Manually installing a development profile on the device via Xcode -> Devices and Simulators -> Connected -> Device -> Show Provisioning Profiles
- Unpairing and pairing device
- Switching off/on developer mode on device
- Restarting the device and computer
- Cleaning build folder
- Signing in/out of the account in xcode
- Switching on/off "Automatically manage signing"
- Xcode "Download Manual Profiles"
- Delete DerivedData folder

**What does work:**

- Ad Hoc installing app (ad hoc profile does also appear on device)

**Error:**

> Details
>
> Unable to install "[appname]"
>
> Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
>
> Code: -402620395
>
> User Info: {
>
> DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-01-06 00:27:00 0000";
>
> IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
>
> }
>
> --
>
> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
>
> Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
>
> Code: -402620395
>
> User Info: {
>
> DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
>
> MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";
>
> "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
>
> 0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010c696c90
> DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode  235
>
> 1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010c6d32ee
> __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke
> 155
>
> 2   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001020c1e01
> DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership  71
>
> 3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000010c6d3016
> -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]
> 1409
>
> 4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000010c5aa7a0
> __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301
> 3520
>
> 5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001021f7a09
> **DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK**  7
>
> 6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001021f851d
> __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke  196
>
> 7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80a3dc7fb
> _dispatch_call_block_and_release  12
>
> 8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80a3dda44
> _dispatch_client_callout  8
>
> 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80a3e3ac4
> _dispatch_lane_serial_drain  694
>
> 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80a3e45b4
> _dispatch_lane_invoke  366
>
> 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80a3eead7
> _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread  762
>
> 12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80a559ce3
> _pthread_wqthread  326
>
> 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80a558c67
> start_wqthread  15
>
> );
>
> }
>
> --
>
> Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
>
> "device_model" = "iPhone14,3";
>
> "device_osBuild" = "16.2 (20C65)";
>
> "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
>
> "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
>
> "launchSession_state" = 1;
>
> "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
>
> "operation_duration_ms" = 5576;
>
> "operation_errorCode" = "-402620395";
>
> "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
>
> "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
>
> "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
>
> "param_consoleMode" = 0;
>
> "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
>
> "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
>
> "param_debugger_type" = 5;
>
> "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
>
> "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
>
> "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
>
> "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
>
> "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
>
> "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
>
> "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
>
> "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
>
> "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
>
> "param_install_style" = 0;
>
> "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
>
> "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
>
> "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
>
> "param_launcher_style" = 0;
>
> "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
>
> "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
>
> "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
>
> "param_runnable_type" = 2;
>
> "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
>
> "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
>
> "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
>
> "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.2";
>
> "sdk_osVersion" = "16.2";
>
> "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
>
> }
>
> --
>
> System Information
>
> macOS Version 13.1 (Build 22C65)
>
> Xcode 14.2 (21534) (Build 14C18)
>
> Timestamp: 2023-01-05T16:27:00-08:00

Comment: Were you able to get it working? Been having the same issue (both with iPhone X 16.3.1 and an older iPhone 7 15.7.3) Posted here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/726790 but no response yet.

Comment: Apologies for not updating this issue! Apple technical support wasn't helpful for whatever that's worth; I did end up doing a hard reset and restored the phone from a backup - for some reason it started working again. To be honest I'm not convinced that was the fix, but the problem hasn't come back.